# How to store and retrieve pdf files into/from SQLITE database using C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

I want to store and retrieve pdf files into/from SQLITE database, I'm using C#. Any one with an Idea of how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the bytes of the PDF, store that and then do the same the other way. although i would think that saving the PDF on an internal storage and storing the path would be a better option.